TPM limit reached when using OpenAI API and Langchain MapReduceDocumentsChain
I'm trying to use Langchain's MapReduceDocumentsChain in combination with OpenAI's API to summarize a the content of a big document through the following chain (which was copied from Langchain's documentation):
def _create_document_summary_chain(self) -> LLMChain:
        """
        Create the summarization chain
        """
        map_chain = LLMChain(
            llm=self._quick_scan_model.llm, prompt=SummaryPrompt.get_document_summary_map_prompt()
        )
        reduce_chain = LLMChain(
            llm=self._quick_scan_model.llm, prompt=SummaryPrompt.get_document_summary_reduce_prompt()
        )
        combine_documents_chain = StuffDocumentsChain(
            llm_chain=reduce_chain, document_variable_name="docs"
        )
        reduce_documents_chain = ReduceDocumentsChain(
            combine_documents_chain=combine_documents_chain,
            collapse_documents_chain=combine_documents_chain,
            token_max=4000
        )
        return MapReduceDocumentsChain(
            llm_chain=map_chain,
            reduce_documents_chain=reduce_documents_chain,
            document_variable_name="docs",
            return_intermediate_steps=False,
        )

The call to the chain is being made through the following function, which takes in a list of Langchain Document objects that have been chunked beforehand:
async def get_document_summary(self, chunks: list[Document]) -> str:
        """
        Get the summary for a given document text. Use the Langchain map reduce summarizer.
        """

        for i in range(self._retries):
            try:
                response = await self._summary_map_reduce_chain.ainvoke(chunks)

                return response['output_text']

            except Exception as e:
                print(
                    f"Document summarizer attempt {i + 1}/{self._retries} failed...")
                print(f"Error: {e}")
                continue

        return ""

The problem is that when running the chain on big documents (> 500 chunks), i get TPM exceeded error like follows:
An error occurred: RateLimitError: Rate limit reached for default-gpt-3.5-turbo in organization org-xxx on tokens per min. Limit: 90000 / min. Current: 89369 / min. Contact us through our help center at help.openai.com if you continue to have issues.

I tried looking around but no one seems to have the same problem as I do, or at least not when using the same chain as I am.
I also tried playing around with the chunks' size and the token_max parameter, but to no avail.

where are you calling this functioin _create_document_summary_chain

This error is not about chunks' size, but about total amount of tokens you are using.
Your openAI subscription tier currently supports 90,000 tokens per minute. Since you've used 89,369 (from your logs), the error is probably "this request would take you over 90,000 - therefore cannot be completed"
One way to avoid this error without upgrading subscription is to check "current" token usage and implement a cooldown (until next minute begins) before making next request if it gets close to 90,000.

The message you are receiving is related to the OpenAI's rate limit on tokens per minute. Check the docs here to understand the concepts of RPM (requests per minute), RPD (requests per day), TPM (tokens per minute), TPD (tokens per day), and IPM (images per minute). Consider adding some backoff to control the number of tokens you are using to avoid/handle those kinds of errors. Besides that, if adding some minutes between each calls is not feasible, take a look in their usage tiers and consider increasing it if necessary.
Some code examples handling those kinds of errors are available here.
